# Why date filed is not taking null but 1900-01-01?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have been working on a backend i.e. in Sql server 2012. I have declare a field as Date in table i.e. **ParawiseDate datetime**.

And I am passing a NULL to it from C# i.e.

```
sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParawiseDate", NULL);
```

Problem:

It saves the dates as **1900-01-01** instead of **NULL**. I tried `""` and also got saved as **1900-01-01**.

Why ?

Comment: What is `NULL`? `NULL` is not a C# keyword.

Comment: Also avoid `AddWithValue` because its type-inference is not always accurate. Always specify an explicit `SqlDbType` value.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it allow null values in ParawiseDate column.Also instead of passing Null try DBNull.value

```
sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParawiseDate", DbNull.Value);
```

Comment: Lol, posted at same time. Well, that's what he's getting, the default value of Date. there is no null values with that method, that would be defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for DateTime, you can declare the type with "?" , otherwise they would default to 1900-01-01

```
DateTime ? Parameter;
```

Also try passing in

```
typeof(System.DateTime)
```

instead of NULL, on the second parameter

Comment: i did. I already did

Comment: no effect , still same

Comment: I see, sorry, does typeof(System.DateTime)

Answer (score 0):

It is essential to know what binary representation of data is and what casts are allowed. Without that, any programmer is somewhat blind. Regarding this case, in MS SQL default date value is 1900-01-01. In older CLR AddWithValue with DBNull.Value as a value  was equivalent to setting field to default.
I didn't dealt with 4.0 CLR environment, but I may expect that NULL could be casted to DBNull? In any case it is not a date value, or if NULL could be implicitly casted into Date with a default value? (latter would say that MS again steps away from standards, NULL must now be equal to pointer to any object) Most likely an undocumented side-effect.

```
public SqlParameter AddWithValue(
    string parameterName,
    object value
)
```

**Parameters**

- `parameterName` 
  Type: `System.String`
  The name of the parameter.
- `value` 
  Type: `System.Object`
  The value to be added. Use `DBNull.Value` instead of null, to indicate a null value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Date and DateTime cannot be NULL, though field in table can be set to allow null values. Reading no data usually would get result in getting default value, for safety reasons. That requires separate check  (isDBNull?)

Only legitimate values for date in SQL (Microsoft flavor at least) are 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 ,  that should be given explicitly, otherwise a default would be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(NULLIF(t.[ParawiseDate],'') AS DATE) 
FROM tablename t
```